# Convergence in weak$^*$ topology

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be any normed linear space and let $(v_n^*)$ be a sequence of unit vectors in $X^*$. We can guarantee a convergent subsequence of the above sequence in case of reflexive Banach spaces. What can we say in general. Can we find an $v_0^*$ in the unit ball of $X^*$ such that $f(v_n^*)\to f(v_0^*)$ for all weak$^*$ continuous functionals? If not in general, how can we guarantee this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no.

By the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, the unit ball of $X^*$ is compact in the weak$^*$ topology, but it is not necessarily weak$^*$ sequentially compact.

Example: Let $X = \ell_\infty$ and $v_n^*$ be the functional that maps $(x_k) \in X$  to its $n$-th coordinate $x_n$. Then $||v_n^*|| = 1$ but no subsequence of $(v_n^*)$ is weak$^*$ convergent: take a subsequence $(v_{n_k}^*)$ and define $f \in \ell_\infty$ by $f_{n_{2k}} = 1$ and $f_{j} = 0$ otherwise. Then $f(v^*_{n_k})$ does not converge (it attains the values 1 and 0 infinitely many times).

Note that we can, however, find a weak$^*$ convergent *subnet* of $(v_{n}^*)$ by the above-mentioned weak$^*$ compactness of the unit ball.

A sufficient condition for this to hold is when $X$ is separable, which makes the unit ball of $X^*$ weak$^*$ metrizable, and on metrizable spaces compactness and sequential compactness coincide.